# Issue with Brightness When Changing Texture in a React Three.js Component

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm facing a problem with a React Three.js component where changing the value of the 'texture' prop results in a very bright appearance of the material or texture. I have provided the code for the component below:

```
export default function AnimatedPanorama({ texturesMap, texture, position, textureIndex }) {
  // Component code...
  // const map = useTexture(texture);
  const map = texture;
  const loading = useLoading();

  return (
    <mesh name="panorama" rotation={[0, 0, 0]} scale={[1, 1, -1]}>
      {/* Geometry and other mesh settings... */}
      <meshBasicMaterial
        attach="material"
        ref={material}
        side={BackSide}
        map={map}
        transparent
      />
    </mesh>
  );
}
```

Here's how I'm using the  component:

```
// PanoramaManager component
export const PanoramaManager = ({ panoramas, ...props }) => {
  // Component code...

  const loadedTextures = [];
  panoramas.map((panoImage) => {
    const texture = panoImage.panoramaImage.url; // route of images i.e './px.png','./city.jpg' etc.
    loadedTextures.push(texture);
    return null;
  });
  const texturesMap = useTexture(loadedTextures);

  console.log('Textures filter', texturesMap);

  // Other code...

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        {/* Other components... */}
        <AnimatedPanorama texture={texturesMap[props.current.currentIndex]} />
        {/* Other components... */}
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
};
```

When I change the value of the 'texture' prop in , the material or texture appears very bright, which is not the expected behavior. I have attached an image showing the desired result(Plant image) and the result I'm getting  when I change the texture (Bright one with mannequin).

Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I am thinking this is some issue with colorspace and it is fixed when I pass 'linear' as prop in . But cannot figure out what is the issue.